# I need to send date data from server and then filter elements using date in google.visualization.datatable used in Google Charts

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax, google-visualization

I'm retrieving datetime & other data in my aspx.cs code for making charts using Google Charts and then sending it to the client side code using this code

```
public static List<DataDB> GetData()
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBPieChartConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    conn.Open();
    string cmdstr = "SELECT * from DateData";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdstr, conn);
    SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    adp.Fill(ds);
    dt = ds.Tables[0];
    List<DataDB> dataList = new List<DataDB>();
    int ok = 0, er = 0, tot = 0;
    DateTime datetime;
    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {
        datetime = (DateTime)dr[0];
        ok = Convert.ToInt32(dr[1]);
        er = Convert.ToInt32(dr[2]);
        tot = Convert.ToInt32(dr[3]);
        dataList.Add(new DataDB(datetime, date, ok, er, tot));
    }
    return dataList;
}


[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public static object[] GetChartData()
{
    List<DataDB> data = GetData();

    var chartData = new object[data.Count + 1];
    chartData[0] = new object[]{
            "Info",
            "Ok Records",
            "Errored Records",
            "Total Records"
        };

    int j = 0;
    foreach (var i in data)
    {
        j++;
        DateTime datetime = i.dt;
        chartData[j] = new object[] { datetime, i.OkRec, i.ErRec, i.TotRec};
    }
    return chartData;
}
```

and using this class

```
public class DataDb
{
    public int OkRec = 0;
    public int ErRec = 0;
    public int TotRec = 0;
    public DateTime dt;
    public DataDB(DateTime dt, int OkRec, int ErRec, int TotRec)
    {
        this.dt = dt;
        this.OkRec = OkRec;
        this.ErRec = ErRec;
        this.TotRec = TotRec;
    }
}
```

then I'm using this code is my aspx i.e client side code to retrieve the data and populate the data for google chart

```
var chartData;
$.ajax({
        url: "Default2.aspx/GetChartData",
        data: "",
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; chartset=utf-8",
        success: function (data) {
            chartData = data.d;
        },
        error: function () {
        alert("Error loading data! Please try again.");
        }
        }).done(function () {
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
        });
    });

function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(chartData);
    var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data);
}
```

Now when I'm running this code, it's not showing correct date values and I'm unable to filter based on data using minValue and maxValue because it expects date value in this format: new Date(2000, 8, 5) as given in Google Documentation. So is there any solution to this problem so I can filter my data based on the Date value.

Comment: Could you just format the `DateTime` yourself? Alternatively, see whether the JSON serializer you're can be configured in terms of its `DateTime` formatting - I know Json.NET can.

Comment: will you please share a sample of `data.d` --> `console.log(JSON.stringify(data.d));`

Comment: @WhiteHat thanks but I was able to solve it using the various posts from stack overflow community including yours. I've added a solution, if you know how to dynamically assign values then it'll be of great use.

Comment: @WhiteHat also, if I have to assign multiple values on the X-axis based on whom filtering will be done then how it'll be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after a long day, I was able to solve it by explicitly giving minValue and maxValue. So if someone knows how to get it from the user from a dropdown or something else, then it'll be of much use.

In this code, I'm calling the function GetData and then populating the datatable on the client side instead of the server side.

```
function drawChart() {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                url: 'Default2.aspx/GetData',
                data: '{}',
                success:
                function (response) {
                    drawVisualization(response.d);
                }
            });
        })

        function drawVisualization(dataValues) {
    if (dataValues.length < 1)
        return;

    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('datetime', 'Date');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Ok');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Error');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Total');

    for (var i = 0; i < dataValues.length; i++) {

        var date = new Date(parseInt(dataValues[i].dt.substr(6), 10));

        data.addRow([date, dataValues[i].OkRec, dataValues[i].ErRec, dataValues[i].TotRec]);
    }
 var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
        view.setRows(data.getFilteredRows([{
            column: 0,
            minValue: new Date(2016, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0),
            maxValue: new Date(2017, 12, 12, 23, 59, 59)
        }]));

        var container = document.getElementById('chart_div');
        var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(view, options);
}
```